# MySql group by issue even with aggregated column in group by

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I'm trying to make this query to work

```
select bj.id,
       bj.m_id,       
       bj.b_s_id,
       bj.contact_phone,
       bj.f_a_date,
       bj.source_request_id,
       mw.w_id,
       COUNT(bjhs.id) as hs_count,
       CAST(IFNULL(SUM(bjhs.status), 0) as UNSIGNED) as hs_status
from b_j bj
inner join m_w mw on bj.m_id = mw.m_id
inner join b_j_h_s bjhs on bj.id = bjhs.b_j_id
inner join m_j mj on mj.m_id = bj.m_id
    and mj.j_id = 4
inner join m_w_j mwj on mwj.m_j_id = mj.id
    and mwj.m_w_id = mw.id
where bj.b_s_id = 2
    and (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (select min(bjhs.created_at)
        from b_j_h_s bjhs
        where bjhs.b_j_id = bj.id
        group by bjhs.b_j_id
        limit 1)) >= 35)
    and bj.deleted_at is null
having hs_count != hs_status
group by bj.id,
       bj.m_id,
       bj.contact_phone,
       bj.f_a_date,
       bj.source_request_id,
       mw.w_id
```

But I'm getting the syntax error. My problem is that I must `group by` (the last one, not the one inside the subquery) the aggregate columns due to `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, but using some or all of the columns I get the same error. What could possibly be the problem and how can I fix it?

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-rocEoJt)

PS. An important note is that I can't change the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` and the MySql version is 8.0.31

Comment: Once you make the corrections in Islam's answer, you only need to group by a single column: `GROUP BY bj.id`, because the subsequent columns are functionally dependent on that column. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html for details on this feature of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few issues:

- `having hs_count != hs_status` should be defined after `group by`
- `mw.w_id` should be `mw.m_id`
- column `bj`.`bariatric_status_id` doesn't exist in the shared schema

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ddKIcIwP)

Comment: Worked! Thx. The `mw.w_id` should be in the table, I've updated the fiddle to reflect that. `bj.bariatric_status_id` should be `bj_b_s_id`, also updated in the fiddle and in the question